# Unexpected behavior of GeometricTransformation

Tags: bugs, geometry, geometric-transform

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2 or later. Fixed in 13.3.1 on Windows 10**

---

I have the following mapping on the complex plane:
$$
z \mapsto \tau \mu  z-1,
$$
where $\mu$ is complex, $\tau$ is real number. I want to draw the image of left unit semidisk and play with $\tau$.

```
μ = 0.16255558520216132` + 0.1849493244071408` I;

pic[τ_] := Block[{d, ds},
   d = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 3 π/2}];
   ds =
    Fold[GeometricTransformation, d,
       {RotationTransform[Arg@#, {0, 0}],
        ScalingTransform[τ Abs@# {1, 1}],
        TranslationTransform[{-1, 0}]
        }] & @ μ;
   Graphics@{Gray, d, Red, Opacity[.5], ds}
   ];

Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Show[pic[τ], Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> zz {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}},
   ImageSize -> 400
   ],
 {τ, 0.01, 1000, 0.01},
 {zz, 0.01, 10, 0.01}
 ]
```

Here `zz` is introduced to control zooming. The problem is that I get different (wrong) images for different zooms. It is clearly seen for big $\tau$'s.

[image][image][image]

It looks very like a bug, but I can not rule out that I'm making some silly mistake (Mathematica 8.0.4).
So, what is the problem here and what is the best way of doing the job (I have several mappings for different $\mu$ actually)?

Comment: I'd have implemented `pic[]` this way: `pic[τ_] := Block[{d, ds}, d = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 3 π/2}]; ds = GeometricTransformation[d, Composition[TranslationTransform[{-1, 0}], ScalingTransform[τ Abs[μ] {1, 1}], RotationTransform[Arg[μ], {0, 0}]]]; Graphics @ {Gray, d, Red, Opacity[.5], ds}]`

Comment: Here's another way to visualize your transformation of a disk: `ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[τ μ r Exp[I θ] - 1]], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, π/2, 3 π/2}]]`

Comment: @J.M. thank you very much! Unfortunately `Composition` produces the same erroneous result. `ParametricPlot` is a viable alternative. Still the problem with composite `GeometricTransformation`s remains.

Comment: Minimal example of the problem: Evaluate `Graphics@GeometricTransformation[Disk[],Composition[ScalingTransform[{800,800}],RotationTransform[0.1,{0,0}]]]` and resize the graphic with the mouse.

Comment: "Unfortunately `Composition` produces the same erroneous result." - I suppose so; all I did was to shorten the code you used for producing the transformed disk `ds`.

Comment: @SimonWoods +1. And for `Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, a}]`, if non-empty `EdgeForm` is used, if `a` is close enough to `2*Pi`, the edge and the filled body "jump" together, if `a` is far away from `2*Pi`, say `3*Pi/2`, the edge alone seems working right.

Comment: You can apply the transformations beforehand to the key-coordinates of the disk, which transforms `Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {α, β}]` to `Disk[{-1, 0}, τ Abs[μ], {α, β} + Arg[μ]]`. This explicit form will work fine with `Graphics`.

Comment: Fixed in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is surely a bug.  The misbehavior certainly persists through V10.2.  In fact, the two images below are of the same computation.  The only difference is where they appear on the screen (as I scrolled the notebook, the transformed red disk jumped around).

```
μ = 0.16255558520216132` + 0.1849493244071408` I;

pic[τ_] := Block[{d, ds, arc},
   d = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, 3 π/2}];
   ds = GeometricTransformation[d, 
       TranslationTransform[{-1, 0}] . 
        ScalingTransform[τ Abs@# {1, 1}] .
        RotationTransform[Arg@#, {0, 0}]] &@ μ;
   Graphics@ {Gray, d, Red, Opacity[.5], ds}];

Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Show[pic[τ], Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> 100 zz , 
   ImageSize -> 222],
 {τ, 0.01, 1000, 0.01}, {zz, 0.01, 10, 0.01}]
```

[image]
[image]

As others have observed, `PlotRange` and `ImageSize` can affect what is displayed.

Note that the graphics are sent to the front end with the disk inside `GeometricTransformationBox` (one with my code, three nested ones with the OP's code).  They appear to be correct, so the issue is with the front end (or possibly the GPU, I suppose).  The workarounds by [Silvia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia) and [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) avoid the use of `GeometricTransformationBox`.  This sort of misbehavior has been noted since, e.g. [Weird behaviour when using Scale, Rotate in Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66060/weird-behaviour-when-using-scale-rotate-in-graphics/91582#91582).

Comment: This bug seems to be related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139719/280