# Animating mathematica.se logo

Tags: graphics, animation

As we all know our site's logo was [completely generated by Mathematica](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/build-your-own-logo-with-mathematica-and-a-few-friends/). I suppose it is quite natural to make the next step -- to generate the animated version of this logo. There's a lot of space for creativity here, and I suggest to consider the following options.

1. Animated process of construction from scratch, as it is described in Verbeia's blog post.
2. Animated morphing of original pentagonal star to the current heptagonal one (J.M.'s idea in the comment)
3. Some less fussy, a neutral animation of the logo itself, more suitable for placing on webpages.

Comment: I'd sure like to see somebody automagically morph a hyperbolic pentagon to a heptagon...

Comment: @J.M. You mean something like a flash shape tween between the two?

Comment: @VF1, yes, something like that...

Comment: If the intention is to change the static logo at the top of each mathematica.se page to a dynamic logo, please don't: it needlessly wastes a bit of bandwidth and, more significantly, distracts from the content. (As a programming exercise, that's another matter.)

Answer (score 58):

Let me join.

[image]

```
logo = Cases[
   p7 /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. shrink /. shrink /. colour3[] /. colour4["SunsetColors", 1, 28/34] , {c__, Polygon[pts__]}, \[Infinity]];
logo = SortBy[logo, First];
p = Evaluate[InterpolatingPolynomial[{
     {0, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {Pi, {Pi, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {2 Pi, {2 Pi, 0, 0, 0}}},#]] &;
pp[a_] := If[Abs[a - Pi] < .6, Pi, p@a];(*to stabilize flickering*)
nf = 37;(*number of frames*)
frames = Table[
   Graphics[Thread[Rotate[logo, p@angle]],
    PlotRange -> 1.2, ImageSize -> 240
    ],
   {angle, 0, 2 Pi, (2 Pi)/(nf - 1)}];
ListAnimate@frames
```

Comment: The only annoying issue is this polygon jumping. I think this is a numerical instability artefact in `Rotate`.

Comment: Have you tried using `RotationTransform` instead?

Comment: Not really, but I'm pretty sure that it won't help. This is possibly related to this problem: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9560/219

Answer (score 53):

Breathing with occluded borders, per Toad's request:

[image]

Run the following command to get the *Mathematica* code

```
NotebookPut@ImportString[Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten@ImageData[
               Import@ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqjJ9.png","Byte"],"NB"]
```

Comment: [code or it didn't happen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5997622#5997622)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Here the upload code http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/193 and here a palette http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/771/193 (although this one seems to work only on some platforms)

Comment: To the future visitors who might face a problem running the code: see [my comment here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/771/for-sale-three-potentially-useful-palettes#comment10730_771)

Answer (score 42):

As per the [blog](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/07/build-your-own-logo-with-mathematica-and-a-few-friends/):

```
Export["breathing.gif", Table[Graphics[
    p7 /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. shrink /. shrink /. colour3[] /.
    colour4["SunsetColors", 1, 28/34] /. curve /. bolicsn[(1 - Cos[2 \[Pi] t])/2], 
  ImageSize -> 150], {t, 0, 1, 0.05}]];
```

[image: breathing]

Some good old fashioned colour cycling:

```
Clear[f];
f[c_] /; c > 2 := c - 2;
f[c_] /; c > 1 := 2 - c;
f[c_] := c;

colour4c[s_: "SunsetColors", a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=
  Polygon[v_] /; Length[v] == 4 :>
    {ColorData[s, f[c + a - b Norm[PolygonCentroid[v]]]], Polygon[v]}

Export["ColourCycleLogo.gif", Table[Graphics[
    p7 /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. shrink /. shrink /. colour3[] /.
    colour4c["SunsetColors", 1, 28/34, t], 
  ImageSize -> 150], {t, 0, 2, 0.05}], "DisplayDurations" -> ConstantArray[0.05, 41]];
```

[image: colours]

Comment: The first one is my favorite so far. +1!

Comment: Alternatively: `f[c_] := 1 - Abs[1 - c]`

Answer (score 42):

Who wanted the automagic? :)

[image]

```
mmastar[as_, nn_: 1] := Graphics[
   Scale[#, 1/max@#, {0, 0}] &[
    Polygon[pt /@ as] /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink /. 
          shrink /. shrink /. colour3[] /. colour4[] /. curve /. 
     bolicsn[nn]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> 0.025];
da = 0.0001;
max[zu_] := 
  Cases[zu, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, \[Infinity]] // Norm // Max;
pt[a_] := {Sin@a, Cos@a};
pts0 = Range[ 0, (2 - 2/5) Pi, 2 Pi/5] // N
pts1 = Append[Insert[pts0, pts0[[2]] - da, 2], pts0[[-1]] + da]
pts2 = Range[Pi/7, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/7] // N
ptsat[t_] := (1 - t) pts1 + t pts2;
nn0 = 1; nn1 = 0.0001;
nat[t_] := (1 - t) nn0 + t nn1;
frames = Table[mmastar[ptsat[t], nat[t]], {t, 0, 1, 1/16}] // Reverse;
ListAnimate[frames]
```

Comment: Excellent, +1 - although you've shown the official logo upside down :)

Comment: @cormillion, fixed! In previous version it was `pts2 = Range[2 Pi/7, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/7] // N`.

Answer (score 35):

Load some images:

```
size = {200, 200};
foot = ImageResize[Import[
   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Monty_python_foot.png"
  ], size];
spikey = ImageResize[Import[
   "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bf/MathematicaSpikeyVersion8.png"
  ], size];
mse = ImageResize[Import[
   "https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjrEY.png"
  ], size];
```

Crop them, squash them, transform them:

```
feet = Table[ImageCrop[foot, size {1, k}, Top], {k, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];
spoke = Table[ImageResize[spikey, size {1, k}], {k, 0.9, 0.1, -0.1}];
logos = Table[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[mse, 
  FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {1, 0},
    {0.5, 0.5} + {-(1/(-2 - 2 Cos[t])), (-4 - 3 Cos[t] + 8 Sin[t])/(8 + 8 Cos[t])},
    {0.5, 0.5} + {1/(-2 - 2 Cos[t]), (-4 - 3 Cos[t] + 8 Sin[t])/(8 + 8 Cos[t])}},
    {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}][[2]], Padding -> White], {t, 0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/40}];
squish = Table[ImageCrop[logos[[1]], size {1, k}, Top], {k, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];
```

Assemble them together:

```
a = ImageAssemble[List /@ #] & /@ Thread[{feet, spoke}];
b = ImageAssemble[List /@ #] & /@ Thread[{Reverse@feet, squish}];
c = logos;
d = ConstantArray[Last@logos, 5];
```

Animate:

```
Export["logoanimate.gif", Join[a, b, c, d]]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: ahhahahahaha....

Comment: "too silly...."!

Comment: Finally, something completely different!

Comment: Ah, finally the foot. Where are the mints?

Answer (score 32):

Here's a spinning "3D version" of the logo

[image]

Using the code from meta/blog to create the logo (assigned to the variable `logo`), continue with the following steps:

```
side[o_] := Block[{z, pts = Partition[
    Table[N[{Cos[t], Sin[t], z}], {t, Pi/14, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/7}], 2, 1, 1]},
    Composition[Polygon, Flatten[#, 1] &] /@ Thread[{pts /. z -> o/2, Reverse /@ pts /. z -> -o/2}]
]

logo3D = With[{d = 0.1}, 
    Graphics3D[{
        {EdgeForm@None, #}, 
        {EdgeForm@None, FaceForm@RGBColor[0.5995136280878135`, 0.20347121886943803`, 0.37787606421753417`], side@d}
        }, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"
    ] & @@ (logo /. Polygon[x__] :> Polygon[{x /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, d/2}, 
        x /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, -d/2}}])
]

frames = Table[Graphics3D[
        {Rotate[First@logo3D, x, {0, 1, 0}]},
        Lighting -> "Neutral",
        ViewAngle -> 35 Degree, ViewVector -> {0, 0, 3.5},
        ViewCenter -> {1, 1, 1}/2, ViewRange -> All, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
        Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400
    ], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}
];

Export["spin.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.05];
```

A "true 3D version" of the logo would involve raised and beveled profiles for the various inner decorations, but that's considerably harder.

Comment: Cool! Perhaps it will look more spectacular with removed gray polygons. The holes will make this "more three-dimensional".

Comment: and that is considerably harder

Comment: @faleichik I agree, and not just that, one would also need to bevel the various polygons "nicely" to give it depth and structure. As I mentioned in the last line, it's a much harder problem :)

Comment: OK, now I see why it is more involved than I thought.

Answer (score 26):

A very rough interpretation, which I hope might at least give some ideas:

```
(* Final image *)
fin = (p7 /. triangulate /. moretriangles /. shrink
      /. shrink /. shrink /. colour3[] /. colour4["SunsetColors", 1, 28/34]);
icycle[ j_, k_] := 
      Table[Graphics[fin[[1 ;; i, j, k]], PlotRange -> 1], {i, 7}] 
kcycle[i_, j_] := 
      Table[Graphics[fin[[i, j, 1 ;; k]], PlotRange -> 1], {k, 4}]
raster = Rasterize/@
    Prepend[Drop[
       Module[{c}, 
        Flatten@
         {Table[(c = icycle[1, 1 ;; m])~Join~Reverse[c], {m, 4}], 
          Table[(c = kcycle[1 ;; 7, 1 ;; m])~Join~Reverse[c], {m, 4}]}], -4],
   Graphics[{White, Rectangle[]}]];
Export["logo.gif", raster]
```

[image]

Comment: nice! On the other hand I wouldn't want to have this amount of flickering on my webpage!

Comment: @chris thanks.  I was just having fun with this, and this is the end result.  I'd love to play with it some more though and maybe get something smother if I have time.

Comment: aaah! Motion sickness!

Comment: Good for the tip of a nerd's Christmas tree

Answer (score 25):

Somewhat belatedly, here is a version that starts from random points and slowly coalesces into the logo.

Begin with the logo from the blog entry which is here called `img`, and apply a [jitter filter](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ImageJitterFilter/) which randomizes the position of each pixel within a region of specified size. By starting with a large region (100 pixels by 100 pixels) and shrinking down to 1 by 1, the image changes from a point cloud into a geometric object.

```
video = Table[
   ImageFilter[RandomChoice[Flatten[#, 1]] &, img, i, Interleaving -> True], 
     {i, {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Not very interesting, but I learnt a few things...

```
tab = Table[Show[
    Graphics[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]],
    i (* where i is the final graphic produced by Verbeia's blog post *)  
     /. 
     {GrayLevel[0.85] -> Opacity[0],
      Polygon[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] -> 
       {
        Scale[Rotate[Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], 2 Pi t, {0, 0}], t, {0, 0}]
       }
      }
    ],
   {t, 0, 1, 0.02}]; 

Export["stack-logo.gif", Flatten[Join[tab, Reverse[tab]]]]
```

[image: stack overrun]