# How to get the real PlotRange using AbsoluteOptions?

Tags: graphics, bugs, graphics3d, options

**Bug fixed in 13.0.0**

---

The problem in general involves the unreliable behaviour of `AbsoluteOptions` when option values are implicitly specified (e.g. `Automatic`, `All`, `Full`, etc.), for example the graphics below clearly has a different plot range than the one reported by `AbsoluteOptions`:

```
{g = Graphics[{}, Frame -> True], AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]}
```

[image]

---

### Original example

For demonstrating the problem, have a look at the following example, and try adjusting the rotation angle `a` and/or the `Locator` position, comparing the real `PlotRange` of `pic` indicated by the frame-ticks with the one under the graph obtained by `AbsoluteOptions[pic, PlotRange]`:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pic},
  Column[{
    pic = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
       GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[a]],
       Red, Point[p]},
      Frame -> True],
    p,
    AbsoluteOptions[pic, PlotRange]
    }]
  ],
 {{a, 0}, 0, 2 Pi},
 {{p, {.1, .2}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As shown in the screen capture above, in my **Mathematica 9.0** on **Windows 7 64-bit** system, the `PlotRange` from `AbsoluteOptions` is not consistent with the real range. And the angle `a` seems to do nothing with it.

Additional tests in my system suggest this problem is not restricted to the presence of `RotationTransform`, but comes with the `GeometricTransformation`. And it happens not only on `Graphics` but also on `Graphics3D`.

So my questions are:

- What is going on here?
- How can I obtain the real `PlotRange` of the `Graphics`/`Graphics3D` when there are  `GeometricTransformation`s in it?

Comment: I wish there was a collection with all the unexpected behaiviours of `AbsoluteOptions`

Comment: @ssch Hmm.. I'm not sure this is a behavior of `AbsoluteOptions` or `GeometricTransformation`. After all the latter one has [records](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9560/17) too.

Comment: In previous versions `AbsoluteOptions` had several problems with `PlotRange` and `Ticks` (at least).

Comment: @belisarius I see.. So I have an answer to my first question. What about the second one? Is there any idea on how to get the real `PlotRange`?

Comment: @Silvia What does `AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[Table[Sin@x, {x, 0, 5, .05}]], PlotRange]` returns in v9?

Comment: @belisarius It's `{PlotRange -> {{0., 101.}, {-0.999923, 0.999784}}}` here.

Comment: @Silvia Well, in v8 it returns `{PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}}`, so I guess I any efforts done in another version will not be useful for you

Comment: I get same as Silvia in v8.0.4 linux64

Comment: @belisarius Thanks a lot:) It looks like I'd test the range manually by now, and wait and see if any ideas come up with from others.

Comment: @Silvia Do you think that `GeometricTransformation` is relevant here? In my understanding, the problem boils down to this simple example which returns wrong values: `g = Graphics[{}, Frame -> True]; Print[g]; AbsoluteOptions[g, PlotRange]`. I hope you don't mind that I added this to your Q to make it more general, if so, please feel free to revert.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I completely agree with you. Thanks very much for the improvement!

Comment: @belisarius V8 OS X `AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[Table[Sin@x, {x, 0, 5, .05}]], PlotRange]` gives the right result. I think it is Windows that gives problems. From memory adding `PlotRange->All` or `PlotRange->Full` might fix.

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132755/280

Comment: It is sad users still need to hack their way in to get such a vital information...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you for the prompt edit. I feel very thankful this is fixed! :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### UPDATE

In version 13.0.0 the described long-standing bug in determining `PlotRange` via `AbsoluteOptions` is fixed.

---

### Original answer

`AbsoluteOptions` is known as very buggy function and the bug in determining the true `PlotRange` has very long history...

You could try [my `Ticks`-based workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7281206/590388) for getting the complete `PlotRange` (with `PlotRangePadding` added):

```
completePlotRange[plot:(_Graphics|_Graphics3D|_Graph)] := 
  Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], ImageResolution -> 1]]

Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pic}, 
  Column[{pic = 
     Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
       GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[a]], 
       Red, Point[p]}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0], p, 
    AbsoluteOptions[pic, PlotRange], completePlotRange[pic]}]], {{a, 
   4}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{p, {.1, -.6}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image: screenshot]

### EDIT

One can get the exact `PlotRange` (without the `PlotRangePadding` added) with the following function:

```
plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
  Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
       Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], 
      ImageResolution -> 1]]

Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pic}, 
  Column[{pic = 
     Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
       GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[a]], 
       Red, Point[p]}, Frame -> True], p, 
    AbsoluteOptions[pic, PlotRange], plotRange[pic]}]], {{a, 4}, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {{p, {.1, -.6}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image: screenshot]

### EDIT 2

Here is timing comparison of various ways to get real `PlotRange`:

```
completePlotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
  Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], ImageResolution -> 1]]
completePlotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph), format_] := 
  Last@
   Last@Reap[
     ExportString[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], format]]

pic = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
    GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[.3]]}, 
   Frame -> True];
Print[{#, 
     AbsoluteTiming[
      First@Table[
        completePlotRange[pic, #], {100}]]}] & /@ {"RawBitmap", "BMP",
    "WMF", "EMF", "SVG", "PDF", "EPS"};
```

> {RawBitmap,{2.8931655,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {BMP,{3.0201728,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {WMF,{4.3242473,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {EMF,{4.0182298,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {SVG,{3.1461800,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {PDF,{16.9799712,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

> {EPS,{7.3074179,{{-0.32158,0.981396},{-0.0250171,1.27587}}}}

```
AbsoluteTiming[First@Table[completePlotRange[pic], {100}]]
```

> {2.3991372, {{-0.32158, 0.981396}, {-0.0250171, 1.27587}}}

One can see that `Rasterize` with `ImageSize -> 0` is the fastest.

### UPDATE 3

Here is purely `Dynamic` implementation of the same idea:

```
plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
 Reap[NotebookDelete[
    First@{PrintTemporary[
       Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
        Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
        DisplayFunction -> Identity, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
        ImageSize -> 0]], FinishDynamic[]}]][[2, 1]]

completePlotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D | _Graph)] := 
 Reap[NotebookDelete[
    First@{PrintTemporary[
       Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
        Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
        DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0]], 
      FinishDynamic[]}]][[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This bug has been annoying me many times, good to finally have a proper workaround.

Comment: Very nice idea +1

Comment: Would you expect it to work on `ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 2}] // completePlotRange`?

Comment: @chris That gives correct `PlotRange` from the start, either way: Change `Ticks` to `FrameTicks` and you might want `PlotRangePadding->0` as well, result will be for all sides, not just x and y

Comment: @chris Yes, it should work correctly to any `Graphics` although for such things as `LogPlot`, `LogLogPlot` etc. it will not respect logarithmic `Ticks`: for example, for `LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}]` it returns plot range consistent with `Show[LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}], Ticks -> Automatic]`.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot! Only a small problem for 2D cases that when `a` is small (say `0.1`), both functions give `Last[{}]`. But everything seems working fine for 3D cases.

Comment: @Silvia I think it is due to a FrontEnd <−> kernel communication conflict between `Manipulate` and `Rasterize` (the latter also uses FrontEnd). Outside of `Dynamic` constructs it is OK, try: `Graphics[{FaceForm[],EdgeForm[Black],GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[],RotationTransform[.01]]}]//plotRange`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I see. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alexey I've extended your marvellous code with `Graph` functionality. I also realized that if you have `Frame -> True` (at least for graphs) it is necessary that the frame is turned off inside the function, so added that too.

Comment: @István Thanks. See also the `UPDATE 3` section. Probably is could be improved further...

Comment: @Alexey Nice, clever idea to use `PrintTemporary`! This is fast enough for my purpose.

Comment: Finally! Thanks fo reporting the v13 advancement.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another way using hidden functions that returns the plot range + padding...

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange @ Graphics3D[{}]
(*
   {{-1.04167, 1.04167}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}}
*)


Charting`get2DPlotRange @ Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}]
(*
   {{-0.12, 6.12}, {-1.04, 1.04}}
*)
```

The second argument of `` Charting`get2DPlotRange `` specifies whether padding should be calculated or not. Here, padding is ignored:

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}], False]
(*
   {{0, 6}, {-1., 1.}}
*)
```

...except that `` Charting`get2DPlotRange `` doesn't work on simple `Graphics[{}]` -- either of the OP's examples.

```
Charting`get2DPlotRange@Graphics[{}]
(*
   {{-0.02, 1.02}, {-0.02, 1.02}}
*)

Charting`get2DPlotRange@
 Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
   GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[Pi/4]], Red,
    Point[{2, 2}]}, Frame -> True]
(*
   {{-0.02, 1.02}, {-0.02, 1.02}}
*)
```

But `` Charting`get3DPlotRange `` seems more reliable (so far):

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = Graphics3D[{Translate[Cuboid[], RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {10, 3}]]}, Axes -> True]
Charting`get3DPlotRange[g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*
   {{-3.8777, 4.41753}, {-4.07619, 5.44314}, {-4.55333, 5.98243}}
*)
```

Comment: This is Great! With Alexey's method now we have full solution for any graphics!

Comment: @MichaelE2 (+1) Note that ``Charting`get2DPlotRange`` is based only on `Options` and `AbsoluteOptions`, so we cannot expect much from it. ``Charting`get3DPlotRange`` is more interesting: it is based on ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`AbsoluteOptions[FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[nbobj],Graphics3DBoxOptions]]``. I have made an analog for `Graphics` but it does not work as expected. It is clear that ``FrontEnd`AbsoluteOptions`` just does not currently support `Graphics`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Nice digging!

Answer (score 9):

I've enhanced my `GraphicsInformation` function to return both the actual and the base [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange). Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

and load with:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

Then:

```
GraphicsInformation @ Graphics[{}, Frame -> True]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{23., 1.5}, {17., 0.5}}, "ImageSize" -> {360., 352.463}, 
>    "PlotRangeSize" -> {335.5, 334.963}, "ImagePaddingSize" -> {24.5, 17.5}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-1.04167, 1.04167}, {-1.04, 1.04}}, 
>    "BasePlotRange" -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}}

Another example:

```
GraphicsInformation @ ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{17., 1.5}, {17., 0.5}}, "ImageSize" -> {360., 359.}, 
>    "PlotRangeSize" -> {341.5, 341.5}, "ImagePaddingSize" -> {18.5, 17.5}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-0.145833, 7.14583}, {-0.0416667, 2.04167}}, 
>    "BasePlotRange" -> {{0., 7.}, {0., 2.}}}

Answer (score 7):

A completely stupid workaround that perhaps someone knows how to automate:

- Create a Graphics object
  `Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[1.]]}]`
- Right click the Graphics and select *Get Coordinates*
- Drag around a bit in the graphics
- `AbsoluteOptions[< Put the object here >, PlotRange]` gives the correct `PlotRange`

It also works by opening Drawing Tools and making a point (or anything else)

Comment: LOL Might be a nice clue :)

Comment: Perhaps you can make an outstanding answer out  of this one. Check the packets JFultz mentioned on chat: StringCases[
 Flatten@MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
    FrontEnd`NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket[]][[1, 1, 4]], ___ ~~ 
  "Mouse" ~~ ___]

Comment: @belisarius Managed to crash my kernel a few times, but otherwise didn't get a reaction

Answer (score 6):

I filed a bug report with Wolfram about this issue, and they said

> `AbsoluteOptions` seems to be returning the range for `PlotRange -> Automatic`.
>   I have forwarded a report of the issue to our developers, using the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the report! Nice to know that!