# How to catch the "Preemptive" evaluations from within the main loop?

Tags: front-end, evaluation

When trying to make an optimized version of my [`plotRange` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280) I faced a problem of catching the `"Preemptive"` evaluations generated by the FrontEnd from withing the main evaluation loop.

Consider the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
xr[r__] := (xRange = {r}; None);
yr[r__] := (yRange = {r}; None);
nb = CreateDocument[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Ticks -> {xr, yr}]}];
{xRange, yRange}
Pause[1];
{xRange, yRange}
NotebookClose[nb]
```

> {xRange, yRange}
>
> {{-0.392699, 19.2423}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}}

One can see that the first evaluation of `{xRange, yRange}` returns undefined symbols because at the moment of its evaluation the functions `xr` and `yr` are still not evaluated via a `"Preemptive"` link by the FrontEnd. But after waiting one second these functions are already evaluated and `xRange`, `yRange` are defined. Because I need these values for further evaluations I need to delay the main loop until the `"Preemptive"` evaluations will be done. (An alternative solution would be to force the FrontEnd to perform its evaluations in the main loop.)

One possible way to solve the problem is to initiate a `Dialog` which will wait for the `Return` generated by the FrontEnd. But `"Preemptive"` evaluations go past the `Dialog` and do not allow the return from it (the following code freezes the kernel):

```
Dialog[xr[r__] := (xRange = {r}; None);
 yr[r__] := (yRange = {r}; None; NotebookClose[nb]; 
   Return[{xRange, yRange}]);
 nb = CreateDocument[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, 
     Ticks -> {xr, yr}]}];]
```

Is it possible to catch the `"Preemptive"` evaluations from the main loop in some way?

### UPDATE

Here is a comparison of my original `Rasterize`-based version and the new `FinishDynamic`-based:

```
gr = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}];
plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D)] := 
 Quiet@Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> True, 
       Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), DisplayFunction -> Identity], 
      ImageResolution -> 1]]
Table[plotRange[gr], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming

plotRange[plot : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D)] := 
 Quiet@Last@
   Last@Reap[(nb = 
       CreateDocument[{Show[plot, Axes -> True, 
          Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &), PlotRangePadding -> None, 
          DisplayFunction -> Identity]}, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
        WindowFrame -> "Frameless", WindowElements -> {}, 
        WindowSize -> 1, Antialiasing -> False, Editable -> False, 
        Magnification -> 1, Saveable -> False, 
        WindowClickSelect -> False, WindowFloating -> False, 
        WindowFrameElements -> {}, WindowMovable -> False, 
        WindowSelected -> False, WindowTitle -> ""];
      FinishDynamic[]; NotebookClose[nb])]
Table[plotRange[gr], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.828125, Null}
>
> {8.406250, Null}

The original `Rasterize`-based version is 3 times faster.

Comment: I got `{{-0.392699, 19.2423}, {-1.04167, 1.04167}}` from both of the two evaluations. My system: v9 on win7 64bit.

Comment: I reproduced it in v9 on Windows, but failed to reproduce it on my Macbook Air.  But this behavior depends upon the ordering of `Dynamic` evaluations.  Those orderings are specifically not guaranteed by Mathematica.

Comment: @JohnFultz Does it mean that the code `Reap[Rasterize[Show[plot, Ticks -> (Sow[{##}] &)]]][[2, 1]]` do not guarantee that the ordering of ranges will always be standard: `{xRange, yRange}` and sometimes one can get `{yRange, xRange}`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov No, I mean that the evaluation of the `Ticks` function, which is acting like a `Dynamic` in this case (even though no `Dynamic` was specified, it's resolved in a similar fashion), might be evaluated at any time relative to the ordering of the Shift+Enter evaluations.  It might happen before the `CreateDocument` has finished evaluation, or shortly thereafter, or a very long time thereafter.  That's why it behaves differently on different machines...because there is no guarantee...it's just evaluating when it can.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After the dynamic evaluation (in this case, your plot) has been displayed to the screen but before you wish to access the variables, evaluate:

```
FinishDynamic[];
```

Note that this function isn't selective.  It will force every `Dynamic` in the entire system to update before it continues.