# Basic question about update of dynamic content

Tags: dynamic

Sorry if this has already been answered 50 times, but here it goes: why does

```
x = 0; Row[{Dynamic[x], Button["increment", (x++;
    FinishDynamic[]; Pause[1]; x++)]}]
```

only ever display even values of x? i.e., why doesn't the dynamic content get refreshed after the first `x++`?

Comment: You need to add `Method -> "Queued"` to the button.

Comment: awesome thanks!

Comment: Does this topic answer your doubts? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120397/5478 It is slightly broader but it explains your problem as well.

Comment: yeah it does, thanks again.