# Distorted graphics when using custom ticks and AspectRatio -> Full

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, ticks

**Bug introduced in 7.0.1 or earlier and persists through 12.0**

---

I am having a problem using custom tick specifications along with `AspectRatio -> Full`.
The problem affects both `Ticks` and `FrameTicks`.

An example of the problem:

```
x = MapThread[{#, #2, {0, 0.007}} &, {100 Range@5, {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"}}];

p = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], Ticks -> {x}, AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Giving an explicit AspectRatio produces the output I desire:

```
Show[p, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A plot without the custom ticks is not distorted:

```
Show[p, Ticks -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I wish to understand what is causing the problem and find a way to work around it *besides* specifying a numeric AspectRatio.  I could add a routine to calculate the aspect ratio from the image size but I would rather find a way to make `AspectRatio -> Full` work as intended.

Comment: `AspectRatio::aspr: Value of option AspectRatio -> Full is not a finite positive number or Automatic. >>` :D

Comment: @belisarius Are you saying this has been *removed* in later versions?  v7 help says: **`AspectRatio->Full` specifies that a graphic should be stretched so as to fill out its enclosing region in a Grid or related construct.**

Comment: Is the result of `AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[Range@5, AspectRatio -> Full], AspectRatio]` on v8.0

Comment: On my computer, the tick height is proportional to the *horizontal* PlotRange. The formula seems to be "absolute tick height" = "horizontal PlotRange" X "specified tick height". This does not correspond to what I see on your first graphics

Comment: @andre would you please upload a picture of what *you* see?  Also, what version are you using?

Comment: @belisarius okay, I get the same message, but `AbsoluteOptions` is known to be bugged.

Comment: Then try `FullGraphics[]` instead ... to get the same result

Comment: I'm running v9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8. I get the same output as you (@Mr.Wizard) do when I evaluate your code.

Comment: @belisarius come on man, you know perfectly well that `FullGraphics` is bugged too.  Are you suggesting that this is an invalid option despite the documentation or something else?

Comment: @m_goldberg if that's the case how about an up-vote on the question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, looking more closely, on my screen I see the y-axis is rendered a little differently. The x-axis crosses the y-axis at zero, and the y-axis has tick labels 1, 2, ..., 6. But the elongated x-axis ticks are still there. (Perhaps not quite as elongated)

Comment: Perhaps this code should also be in display at the Ripley museum `p = Plot[Log[r], {r, 1, 600}, ImageSize -> {250, 250}, 
  AspectRatio -> Full]
s = Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[p, Ticks];
Plot[Log[r], {r, 1, 600}, ImageSize -> {250, 250}, s[[1]], 
 AspectRatio -> Full]
Head@First@s
Plot[Log[r], {r, 1, 600}, ImageSize -> {250, 250}, Evaluate@First@s, 
 AspectRatio -> Full]`

Comment: I don't see `y` ticks at all in the first example unless I do `Ticks -> {x, Automatic}` or something, nevertheless, the main problem is there.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for updating the header, and I am sorry to hear that this still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

not a answer

With my Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win 7 your code :

```
x = MapThread[{#, #2, {0, 0.007}} &, {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", 
     "Three", "Four", "Five"}}];

p = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], Ticks -> {x}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

gives :

[image]

This graphics is not exactly the same as yours

One can see that the ticks height is ~ -4, in accordance with the formula :
"absolute tick height" = "horizontal PlotRange" X "specified tick height"

here : ~4 = 600 0.007

If I try another PlotRange :

```
x = MapThread[{#, #2, {0, 0.007}} &, {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", 
     "Three", "Four", "Five"}}];

p = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], Ticks -> {x}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> {250, 250}, PlotRange -> {{1, 300}, Automatic}]
```

I get :

[image]

corresponding to 2 = 300 0.007

etc ...

**Note**

It is easier to play with "positive" ticks and it doesn't change the problem.
Example :

```
x = MapThread[{#, #2, (* here is the difference --> *) {0.007, 0}} &, {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", 
     "Three", "Four", "Five"}}];

p = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], Ticks -> {x}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  ImageSize -> {250, 250}, PlotRange -> {{1, 300}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Once again : ~2 = 300 0.007

Comment: What you show here is what I see with v.9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8 with one difference: I see the y-axis always positioned at `x = 0`. The ticks marks, however, are exactly the same as you show.

Answer (score 5):

### A workaround

This long-term bug is a constant source of pain for *Mathematica* users for many years. After years of customization of plots "by hands" I have figured out what happens and developed a general approach which allows to get the expected output with as little pain as possible. It was even necessary to develop special technical vocabulary in order to avoid ambiguity.

---

#### Definitions:

- **plot range** term here means - the complete plotting range always bounded by `Frame` (even when the `Frame` is not shown) which includes `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` but doesn't include `ImagePadding` and `ImageMargins`
- `internalWidth` and `internalHeight` - correspondingly width and height of the **plot range** in the units of the intrinsic coordinate system of the plot
- `printerPointsWidth` and `printerPointsHeight` - correspondingly the actual width and height of the **plot range** in *priter's points* (or *pixels* - depending on the final export format)
- `xResolution` - how many *priter's points* correspond to the unit horizontal distance in the intrinsic coordinate system of the plot
- `yResolution` - how many *priter's points* correspond to the unit vertical distance in the intrinsic coordinate system of the plot
- `xTickLength` and `yTickLength` - correspondingly the tick mark length specified for horizontal and vertical axis in the custom ticks specification
- `xTickPointsLength` and `yTickPointsLength` - correspondingly the actual tick mark length in *printer's points* obtained for horizontal and vertical axis
- `c` - empirical constant approximately equal to `1.16`

Basic relationships:

```
xResolution = printerPointsWidth/internalWidth

yResolution = printerPointsHeight/internalHeight
```

With [andre's hint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19677/280) I found the mathematical formulae which currently (checked with versions 8.0.4 and 10.3.1) determine the final tick mark lengths in the case of `AspectRatio -> Full` both for vertical and horizontal axes:

```
xTickPointsLength = xTickLength*yResolution*internalWidth*c

yTickPointsLength = yTickLength*xResolution*internalWidth*c
```

These formulae are valid only when `AspectRatio -> Full` and only for custom tick marks specifications.

---

#### Code

Assuming that `plot` is our plot, `internalWidth` and `internalHeight` can be obtained using my [`completePlotRange` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280) in the following way:

```
{internalWidth, internalHeight} = -Subtract @@@ completePlotRange[plot]
```

`printerPointsWidth` and `printerPointsHeight` can be obtained using the [`printerPointsPlotRange` function developed by user LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83659/280):

```
{printerPointsWidth, printerPointsHeight} = printerPointsPlotRange[plot]
```

Now if we want our tick marks to be of length 6 printer's points, we can proceed in the following way:

```
targetPointsLength = 6;
c = 1.16;

xTickLength = targetPointsLength/(yResolution*internalWidth*c)
yTickLength = targetPointsLength/(xResolution*internalWidth*c)
```

---

#### Self-contained example

```
completePlotRange[plot:(_Graphics|_Graphics3D|_Graph)] := 
  Last@
   Last@Reap[
     Rasterize[
      Show[plot, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Ticks -> ((Sow[{##}]; Automatic) &), 
       DisplayFunction -> Identity, ImageSize -> 0], ImageResolution -> 1]];

printerPointsPlotRange = 
    (#[[2]] - #[[1]] &)@
        (Rasterize[Show[#, Epilog ->
            {Annotation[Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]],
                "Two", "Region"]}], "Regions"][[-1, 2]]) &;


plot = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {250, 250}];

{internalWidth, internalHeight} = -Subtract @@@ completePlotRange[plot]
{printerPointsWidth, printerPointsHeight} = printerPointsPlotRange[plot]
{xResolution, 
 yResolution} = {printerPointsWidth, printerPointsHeight}/{internalWidth, internalHeight}
targetPointsLength = 6;
c = 1.16;
xTickLength = targetPointsLength/(yResolution*internalWidth*c)
yTickLength = targetPointsLength/(xResolution*internalWidth*c)

xTicks = MapThread[{#, #2, {0, xTickLength}} &, {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", "Three", 
     "Four", "Five"}}];
yTicks = MapThread[{#, #2, {0, yTickLength}} &, { 
    Range@6, {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"}}];
Show[plot, Ticks -> {xTicks, yTicks}]
```

> ```
> {625., 6.87842}
>
> {240.625, 237.245}
>
> {0.385, 34.4912}
>
> 0.000239941
>
> 0.0214957
> ```
>
> [image: plot]

Now open this figure in MS Paint and ensure that tick marks indeed have length 6 pixels:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your analysis and work-around!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I face the `Ticks` problem for many years regularly. But without the [linked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83659/280) contribution by LLlAMnYP it was not solvable. It is a great shame that such a basic task requires such a huge collective effort to be solved! Even worse, the solution is so ridiculously complicated and hackish! :(

Answer (score 3):

I believe andre already answered the question. I'm only providing this as a reference to myself and others who might need to specify the ticks while having `AspectRatio -> Full`.

The reason I set `AspectRatio` to `Full` is so that I can have more control of the final figure. To try to fix Mr. Wizards problem we can remove the tick length information.

```
x = MapThread[{#, #2} &, {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"}}];
p = Framed@ListPlot[Array[Log, 600], Ticks -> {x}, AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

This gives us a plot with inverted tick marks.

[image]

The key part with the ticks is the information that andre provided:

> "absolute tick height" = "horizontal PlotRange" X "specified tick height"

To create the figure we can do:

```
basicPlot = ListPlot[Array[Log, 600]];
xlen = First@Differences@AbsoluteOptions[basicPlot, PlotRange][[1, 2, 1]];
tickLength = .1;
x = MapThread[
        {#, #2, {0, tickLength/xlen}} &,
        {100 Range@5, {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"}}
    ];
```

`tickLength` is set to .1, in units of the actual plot. This should be changed to the desired length of the ticks.

As a bonus I like to specify where I wish to place my x and y labels:

```
xLabel[x_, pos_] := Graphics[{
        Text[Style[x, 10, FontFamily -> "Arial"], pos, {0, 1}]
    }];
yLabel[x_, pos_] := Graphics[{
        Text[Style[x, 10, FontFamily -> "Arial"], pos, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]
    }];
```

Now we draw the final plot:

```
Framed@Show[
  basicPlot,
  xLabel["X Label", {300, -1}],
  yLabel["Y Label", {-100, 3}],
  AspectRatio -> Full,
  Axes -> None,
  FrameTicks -> {x, Automatic, None, None},
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
  ImagePadding -> {{45, 5}, {45, 5}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImageSize -> {250, 250}
  ]
```

[image]

Notice how I use `ImagePadding` to control how much space I will leave for my labels and where the figure will be placed in the space specified by `ImageSize`. `PlotRangeClipping` needs to be set to `False` so that the labels can be displayed. If you need to clip then mask it.

```
mask = Graphics[{
    Gray,
    Polygon[{
      ImageScaled[{0, 0}],
      ImageScaled[{0, 1}],
      ImageScaled[{1, 1}],
      ImageScaled[{1, 0}],
      ImageScaled[{0, 0}],
      Scaled[{0, 0}],
      Scaled[{1, 0}],
      Scaled[{1, 1}],
      Scaled[{0, 1}],
      Scaled[{0, 0}],
      ImageScaled[{0, 0}]
      }]
    }];
Framed@Show[
  basicPlot,
  mask,
  xLabel["X Label", {300, -1}],
  yLabel["Y Label", {-100, 3}],
  AspectRatio -> Full,
  Axes -> None,
  FrameTicks -> {x, Automatic, None, None},
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
  ImagePadding -> {{45, 5}, {45, 5}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ImageSize -> {250, 250}
  ]
```

[image]

In `mask` change the color to `White`. Once you are done with the final edits to the figure remove the outside frame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Sadly, for your "final plot" I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4vkp.png  Apparently *some* part of this bug has been fixed in later versions, but a form of it still remains.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, what mma version are you using? So, just to be clear the above output was for mma 9.0.1. I still have mm8, I'll try it there.

Comment: v7 still :^) -- anyway, I'm sure this will be helpful to others.

Comment: Good to know. I just checked v8, it works fine there.

Comment: Belated +1 now that I can test this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks! :)