# Image Size using {w,h}

Tags: plotting

Mathematica help file says:

"With ImageSize->{w,h} an object will always be drawn in a $w\times h$ region, and will be sized to fit in the region. "

However:

[image]

Doesn't look like "and will be sized to fit in the region" is working. Am I thinking incorrectly here?

Using Version 10.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here is a trick to see the actual space used by the plot:

```
Grid[{{Plot[Sqrt[100 - x^2], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
      ImageSize -> {250, 100}]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[{{Plot[Sqrt[100 - x^2], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    ImageSize -> {500, 100}]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can see that it did actually use more space (width). Now if you want to widen your plot, this is something else. You can use Aspect ratio for this.

```
Grid[{{Plot[Sqrt[100 - x^2], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> {500, 100}, AspectRatio -> .2]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this does not look too good.
ps. (You can also use `Framed@Plot[...]` to see the actual space used instead of Grid as above)

Comment: Nice answer. Looks like this works as well: `Framed@Plot[Sqrt[100 - x^2], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> {500, 100}, AspectRatio -> Full]`

Comment: It is worth to mention that `AspectRation` should be exactly equal to `100/500`, i.e. `h/w` where `h` and `w` are from `ImageSize->{w,h}`.

Comment: @Alexey Popkov It is a useful point. Alexey, why would not you formulate this as a regular answer?

Comment: @David Be careful of that option!  It can produce weird problems: [(19656)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19656/121)

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Done.

Answer (score 4):

By default `Plot` has `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` which is a definite value:

```
1./GoldenRatio
```

> ```
> 0.6180339887498948
> ```

According to [the Documentation page for `ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) (emphasis mine),

> - With `ImageSize->{w,h}` an object will always be drawn in a $w×h$
>     region, and will be sized to fit in the region.
> - If the object has a **definite aspect ratio that is not $h/w$**, then space
>     will be left around it.

From the above follows that `ImageSize` does not change `AspectRatio` when the latter has a definite value and if you want the plot to fit the `ImageSize` you should explicitly specify `AspectRatio -> h/w` where `h` and `w` are taken from `ImageSize -> {w, h}`:

```
Grid[{{Plot[Sqrt[100 - x^2], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> {500, 100}]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: plot]