# Why does AbsoluteOptions give the wrong answer for ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, options

I'm trying to get the PlotRange from a ListPlot graphic:

```
aa = RandomReal[14, {50}] - 40;
bb = RandomReal[140, {50}] - 40;
plt = ListPlot[Transpose[{aa, bb}], Frame -> True, Axes -> False,PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: Result]

```
AbsoluteOptions[plt, PlotRange]
{PlotRange -> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}}
```

This is clearly wrong, Why?

This happens using version 8.0.0, 64bit under Linux (Fedora).

Comment: It works for me, can you try with a fresh kernel ?

Comment: Can't say why it does this, but if you put `PlotRange -> Automatic`, it will return the correct plot range.
Oh, and with respect to b.g's comment, I have reproduced the issue on Mathematica 9, fresh kernel and all.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, a fresh kernel did not change it

Comment: @jVincent, thanks, but adding PlotRange->Automatic didn't work

Comment: Interesting, what version are you working on?

Comment: Works for me on _Mathematica_ 8.0.4.0 _Fedora 19_ 64bit.

Comment: Thanks Öskå, If we see this inconsistent behavior, does this then indicate either a bug or a configuraton issure?

Comment: It gives the correct range under *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 Win 7 64bit, so I guess if this can be reproduced under v9.0.0, than it is the manifestation of the bug discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/89). Flagging as duplicate.

Comment: @ István Zachar, Thanks! I didn't found this one. The question you found clearly answers mine. First, this behavior is a bug and second, there are some published workarounds.