# Use boundaries of one plot for another

Tags: plotting

I am writing some code in which I combine a `ParametricPlot[]` with a `RegionPlot[]`. *Mathematica* is very good at figuring out appropriate bounds for the `ParametricPlot[]`, and I would like to reuse the same bounds for creating the `RegionPlot[]`. How can I tell *Mathematica* to reuse the bounds?

Comment: If you mean `PlotRange`, then the function `completePlotRange` in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions/18040#18040) to [How to get the real PlotRange using AbsoluteOptions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions) might be of interest.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Doesn't seem necessary in this particular case

Comment: @belisarius I noticed, but I still thought it was a good reference for others, as well as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Show[RegionPlot[x + y < 1/2, Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[Join, {{{x}, {y}}, (PlotRange /. 
                                                            AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])}]]], 
     #] &@ ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: The construction `(PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[#, PlotRange])` can in fact be substituted, I think, by the much simpler `PlotRange[#]`. As far as I can tell this is not documented in the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) documentation, but it does seem to work.

Comment: @episanty Efectivamente. I learnt about that in a recent answer here. Thanks!