# Edit Automatic PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics

if I have a plot let us say

```
Plot[x^2 - 5 x - 10, {x, 0, 8}]
```

I want o check if there is a way to know the automatic plot range and to add or subtract from that range as I need.

I will assume something fictitious like this:

```
Plot[x^2 - 5 x - 10, {x, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> (Automatic + {0, 10})]
```

is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Are you asking about `y` axis? `Plot[x^2 - 5 x - 10, {x, 0, 8}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 8}}]` ?

Comment: Related: "[How to get the real `PlotRange`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18040/280)"

Comment: @Kuba yes I am asking about y axis. thanks for the answer. can that be applied for both sides of y axis (+y and -y)?

Comment: @Algohi It's unclear what it is about. PlotRange padding will not create parts of plot that are not already there. Take as example `Tan[x]`. About `x` axis, isn't it the second argument of `Plot`?

Comment: pretty sure in general you need to generate the plot use `AbsoluteOptions[]` or some such to get the range then re-plot.

Comment: @kuba PlotRangePadding is what I was looking for. It appears I can control both sides of each axes. What is was looking for is something like this : Plot[{10, x^2 - 5 x - 10, -16.5}, {x, 0, 8}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{5, 4}, {10, 20}}]

Comment: @george2079 AbsoluteOptions[] is new to me taht I can get the values of some options. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP confirmed that `PlotRangePadding` is what solves the problem.

```
Plot[x^2 - 5 x - 10, {x, 0, 8},   PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 8}}]
```

Answer (score 5):

just for completeness here is the issue with padding, if automatic ranging clipped the function, `PlotRangePadding` does not recover the clipped portion:

```
 Plot[ 1/x , {x, -1, 1},
     PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {10, 10}}]
```

[image]

Fix by generating the plot first to get the auto generated range then again with  manual padding:

```
 Plot[1/x, {x, -1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> ({#[[1]], #[[2]] + {-10, 10}} &@
      (PlotRange /.  AbsoluteOptions[Plot[ 1/x , {x, -1, 1}]]))]
```

[image]

Comment: you are right about this. I will consider this way also. great thanks.