# Automatic is not always the default option

Tags: options, optional-arguments, default

Contrary to what one might expect, specifying an option to be `Automatic` sometimes changes the output.  For example, by default `Show`'s range is set by the first graphic, but setting `PlotRange -> Automatic` causes it to choose the best range for all the graphics being shown.  Are there any other situations in which `Automatic` is not the default option?  And is there a way to modify the kind of command given at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48562/30780 to use the default rather than the `Automatic` value?

Comment: You will need to read the documentation for the particular function.  In the *Details and Options* section it list all the options and their defaults. These are also links to the options own documentation page where you can get more information. Further down on the function's page in the *Examples | Options* section there are examples for the options in the function.  The *Scope* section also has interesting information on parameter and option values.

Comment: `Show` is a bad example. It actually doesn't have any options with defaults defined for it. A better example is `PlotLegends`. For most plotting functions (maybe all?) the default value is `None`, while `PlotLegends -> Automatic` turns on automatically generated legends.