# Possible bug in PlotRange output

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, version-11

I see strange behaviour of PlotRange in the latest Mathematica:

```
PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

gives `{{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}`

But if we change `PlotRange` to `Full` the output is correct

```
PlotRange /.AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> Full]]    
{{0., 3.14159}, {4.11062*10^-15, 1.81971}}
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I have noticed this problem too. It is a bug new to 11.0.1 and is causing lots of problems for lots of people (I noticed it last week, and there are 2 separate posts about it on stackechange today).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 11.1.0 output is as in version 10.4.1:

```
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

> ```
> {{6.41141*10^-8, 3.14159}, {4.11062*10^-15, 1.81971}}
> ```

Here is output from version 11.0.1:

```
PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[Plot[Sin[x] x, {x, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

> ```
> {{0.`, 1.`}, {0.`, 1.`}}
> ```

So this particular feature of `Plot` is specific to version 11.0 and is changed back in version 11.1. However it isn't a bug in `Plot` or `Graphics` of version 11.0, but it is just another manifestation of the old and well-known [bug in `AbsoluteOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/280) which was simply unmasked in version 11.0.