# Determine the PlotRange of a Graphics object programmatically

Tags: graphics, options

Given some graphics expression, I would like to be able to programmatically find its `PlotRange` in a form of a list containing figures. I just would like to stress that the result in a form `{Automatic,Automatic}` or like `{Automatic,{0,100}}` or comparable is not what I need. Everything must be defined by numbers, such as, for example, `{{0,200},{0,100}}` or alike.

To be more precise, here is an expression of the type I have in mind:

```
expression = Show[{
   PolarPlot[300*Cos[\[CurlyPhi]/2]^2, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, \[Pi]}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Classic", PlotStyle -> Darker[Blue], 
    PlotRange -> {0, 200}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 18, Italic, "TimesNewRoman", Black], 
      Style["y", 18, Italic, "TimesNewRoman", Black]}, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.05], ImageSize -> 400],
   Graphics[{Text[Style["(b)", 24, "Times"], Scaled[{0.92, 0.95}]]}]}]
```

showing this:

[image]

Now, assume I have no idea of this code, but need to get its `PlotRange`.

Any idea?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2091/retrieving-the-imagepadding-in-absolute-units) and `AbsoluteOptions`. If those are not enough, try to use the search. There are already questions on this.

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions) contain an answer to your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use my [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function to obtain this information. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

Then, load it:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

For your example:

```
GraphicsInformation[expression]
"PlotRange" /. %
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{0.5, 18.}, {11.4785, 24.}}, 
>    "ImageSize" -> {400., 261.553}, "PlotRangeSize" -> {381.5, 226.074}, 
>    "ImagePaddingSize" -> {18.5, 35.4785}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-44.5312, 307.031}, {-4.16667, 204.167}}}
>
> {{-44.5312, 307.031}, {-4.16667, 204.167}}

Note that `GraphicsInformation` is more reliable than [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange). For instance, compare:

```
PlotRange[Graphics[{}, Axes->True]]
"PlotRange" /. GraphicsInformation[Graphics[{}, Axes->True]]
```

> {{0., 1.}, {0., 1.}}
>
> {{-1.04167, 1.04167}, {-1.04, 1.04}}

Answer (score 0):

this is not exact but close

```
PlotRange[Graphics[expression[[1]]]]
```

> {{-37.5, 300.}, {0., 194.856}}

Comment: Depends how close initial PlotRange is to the range defined by primitives inside. For `PlotRange -> {-100, 300}` it gives the same result.