# Show additional box border in 3D plot

Tags: graphics3d, boxes, plotting

How to best draw an additional box boder at `{x, y, 0}` as indicated by the red arrow below? `PlotRange` is `Automatic` (do not assume it is `{{0, 100}, {0, 100}, {-50, 50}}` always).

[image]

```
points = RandomReal[100, {100, 3}];
points[[All, 3]] = points[[All, 3]] - 50;
ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

The only idea I have is extracting `PlotRange` with `AbsoluteOptions` and drawing the box border manually. That may be [too difficult for me](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/6208). I use Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`InfinitePlane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfinitePlane.html) without having to get the  `PlotRange` of input plot:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1],
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}]}]]
```

[image]

**Update:**  An alternative that also works in version 9 is to use [`FaceGrids`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html):

```
facegrids = {#, {{}, {0}}} & /@ Join[#, -#] &@Most[IdentityMatrix[3]];
ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1, FaceGrids -> facegrids, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** You can also use `PlotRange` to extract the plot range of a plot object and use it with `Cuboid`:

```
lpp = ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1]; 
rectangle = Transpose[Append[PlotRange[lpp][[;; 2]], {0, 0}]];
Show[lpp, Graphics3D[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], Cuboid @@ rectangle}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Something like this I was hoping for, thanks. Unfortunately ``InfinitePlane`` was only introduced in MMA 10.

Comment: @Frank, please see the update.

Comment: That's truly fantastic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the useful-but-undocumented function `` Charting`get3DPlotRange `` to find the plot range, and use that to make your box:

```
points = RandomReal[{-50, 50}, {100, 3}];
plot = ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1];
{x, y, z} = Charting`get3DPlotRange @ plot;
Show[plot,
    Graphics3D[
        {
            EdgeForm @ Blue,
            FaceForm @ Opacity @ 0.05, (* set to 0 for transparent *)
            Cuboid @@ Thread[{x, y, {0, 0}}]
        }
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I ran into trouble when using this together with ``PlotLegends -> Placed[]``.