# Find bounding box of arbitrary 3d graphics?

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

What's the best workaround for this limitation:

```
RegionBounds[
 BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[{Cone[], Cuboid[]}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Tz. Who downvotes this? @M.R. What about `RegionBounds@RegionUnion[
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[]],
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]]
  ]`?

Comment: The very last item in the `DiscretizeRegion` docs says "DiscretizeGraphics for Graphics3D with multiple volume primitives is not supported", unfortunately. Hence the need for a workaround I suppose :)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I expect the downvote was due to the question originally not having copy-pasteable code :)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I did. Because of the very low quality question for a long term user. No copyable code, not a word about what qualifies as expected output etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange[
 Show[Graphics3D[{Cone[], Cuboid[]}], PlotRangePadding -> None]]
(*  {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}  *)
```

See [How to get the real PlotRange using AbsoluteOptions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-using-absoluteoptions/40237#40237)

If "arbitrary 3d graphics" includes of objects of heterogeneous dimensions, then `get3DPlotRange` still works:

```
Charting`get3DPlotRange[
 Show[Graphics3D[{Cone[], Cuboid[], Point[{0, 0, -3}], 
    Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}}]}], PlotRangePadding -> None]]
(*  {{-2., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-3., 1.}}  *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
RegionBounds@RegionUnion[ 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[]], 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]]
  ]
```

> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}

Answer (score 4):

```
MinMax /@ Transpose[RegionBounds /@ {Cone[], Cuboid[]}]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}