# PlotRangeClipping is not working correctly with ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export, rendering

**Bug introduced in 12.3 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

---

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[3 x]}, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}];

plot=ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}},
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 100}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True];


Export["C:\\plot.png", plot, 
 ImageResolution -> 800]
```

[image]

**Update#1**

As noted in the comment by @cvgmt the above bug is fixed in *Mathematica* 13.0.1, but adding `ColorFunction -> Hue` raises the problem again even in *Mathematica* 13.0.1:

[image]

I tried `RegionFunction` to solve this silly MMA problem, but it did not work with `ListLinePlot` as it does with `Plot`.

```
plot = ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 100}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 1 &)]
```

Comment: Fixed in version 13.0.1

Comment: You have discovered another buggy case for PlotRangeClipping which wasn't fixed in version 13.0.1. Please report it to the tech support.

Comment: any workaround for the moment? and why RegionFunction does not work with ListLinePlot?

Comment: Try `Options[ListLinePlot, RegionFunction]`. You will get the error message: "`RegionFunction` is not a known option for `ListLinePlot`." And see my answer below.

Comment: From the other side, on the Docs page for [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) `ListLinePlot` is listed as supported function. Hence non-working `RegionFunction` is another bug of `ListLinePlot`. Please report it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered another buggy case for `PlotRangeClipping` which wasn't fixed in version 13.0.1. It is worth to know that this bug isn't present in version 8.0.4, so it is a backslide bug. Please report this to the tech support.

As a workaround you can add above the plotted line a white `Polygon` with a hole. The hole should exactly cover the whole `PlotRange`:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[3 x]}, {x, -4, 4, 0.1}];
plot = ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {150, 100}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, ColorFunction -> Hue];

plot2 = Show[plot,
   Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[None],
     Polygon[{{-1.1, -0.51}, {1.1, -0.51}, {1.1, 0.51}, {-1.1, 0.51}} ->
       {{-1, -0.5}, {1, -0.5}, {1, 0.5}, {-1, 0.5}}]}]];

Export["plot.png", plot2, ImageResolution -> 800]
```

The exported file (*Mathematica* 13.0.1):

[image: exported file]

---

You can automate the above approach with the function `fixClipping` defined below:

```
Clear[ClippingPolygon, fixClipping]
ClippingPolygon[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, padding_ : 0.05] := 
  Module[{hole, dX, dY, outer},
   hole = {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}};
   dX = (xmax - xmin)*padding;
   dY = (ymax - ymin)*padding;
   outer = {{xmin - dX, ymin - dY}, {xmax + dX, ymin - dY}, 
            {xmax + dX, ymax + dY}, {xmin - dX, ymax + dY}};
   Polygon[outer -> hole]];
fixClipping[plot_Graphics] := Module[{pr, prp, FullPlotRange},
  {pr, prp} = Values@AbsoluteOptions[plot, {PlotRange, PlotRangePadding}];
  FullPlotRange = pr + prp*{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
  Show[plot, Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[None], ClippingPolygon[FullPlotRange]}]]]
```

How it can be used:

```
plotFixed = fixClipping@plot;
Export["plot.png", plotFixed, ImageResolution -> 800]
```

(The result is as shown above.)

In the *Mathematica* versions 13.0 and above this function should work correctly with non-explicit `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` specifications (for example, `PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, All}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]`).
In the earlier versions for obtaining the padded plot range (`FullPlotRange` in `fixClipping`) one can use [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)'s [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280) instead of [`AbsoluteOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18034/280).

---

**UPDATE in responce to comments**

Here is another solution which doesn't force rasterization and allows exporting the figure in vectors as PDF:

```
Clear[ClippingRectangles, fixClipping2]
ClippingRectangles[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, padding_ : 0.05, pixelFix_ : 0.01] :=
  Module[{pX, fX, pY, fY, pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4},
   {pX, fX} = (xmax - xmin)*{padding, pixelFix};
   {pY, fY} = (ymax - ymin)*{padding, pixelFix};
   pol1 = Rectangle[{xmin - pX, ymin - pY}, {xmin - fX, ymax + pY}];
   pol2 = Rectangle[{xmax + fX, ymin - pY}, {xmax + pX, ymax + pY}];
   pol3 = Rectangle[{xmin - pX, ymin - pY}, {xmax + pX, ymin - fY}];
   pol4 = Rectangle[{xmin - pX, ymax + fY}, {xmax + pX, ymax + pY}];
   GraphicsGroup[{pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4}]
   ];
fixClipping2[plot_Graphics] := 
 Module[{pr, prp, FullPlotRange}, {pr, prp} = 
   Values@AbsoluteOptions[plot, {PlotRange, PlotRangePadding}];
  FullPlotRange = pr + prp*{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
  Show[plot, Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[None], ClippingRectangles[FullPlotRange]}]]]
```

How to use:

```
plotFixed = fixClipping2@plot;
Export["plot.pdf", plotFixed]
```

The disadvantage of this method is that in some situations it may be required to adjust the value of `pixelFix` manually. This value is required due to limited precision of relative positioning of the primitives on the plot by the FrontEnd. Sometimes they may be off by "1 pixel" despite the fact that FrontEnd exports the figure to a high-precision vector format.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. However, this solution is not allowed to export a vector-style plot as pdf or eps.

Comment: @valarmorghulis I updated the answer with an alternative implementation, which doesn't force rasterization when exporting to vector formats.

Comment: @valarmorghulis I've found that for your plots *Mathematica* 13.0.1 has no clipping problems when exporting them as PDF. So the workaround is necessary only for exporting to raster formats.

Comment: thanks for the update!