# Weird behaviour when using Scale, Rotate in Graphics

Tags: graphics, bugs, geometric-transform

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.2.0 or later, fixed in 12.0**

---

*(Edited to simplify drawing)*

I have a drawing of two tangent circles:

```
circles = {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{0, 0.5}, 0.5]};
Graphics[circles, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

But when I draw a transformed version of it, the circles become misaligned in an erratic fashion. It seems to be dependent on the `PlotRange` or something like that:

```
GraphicsGrid@
 Partition[
  Table[Graphics[
    Rotate[Scale[circles, 12, {0, 0}], -45 Degree, {0, 0}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}, ImageSize -> 100], {a, 11, 20}], 
  5]
```

[image]

The error does not occur if either `Scale` or `Rotate` are removed, so apparently the two transformations are interacting badly. But why should they? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

(N.B. This is with a fresh kernel; Mathematica 10.0.1 on Mac.)

---

Right now I'm getting around the problem by defining something like

```
scaledCircles = With[{s = 12}, 
   circles /. Circle[{x_, y_}, r_] :> Circle[{s x, s y}, s r]];
```

and then only applying `Rotate` to it. But that's no way to live.

The documentation states that "When possible, `Normal` will transform the coordinates explicitly" and gives an example of the form `Normal@Scale[Cuboid...]`. So if it worked it would be a nice and automatic way to do my workaround. But `Normal` doesn't work on scaled circles, for no reason I can fathom.

Comment: I observe the same erratic behavior in versions 8.0.4 and 10.0.1 under Windows 7. It depends on the Magnification of the Notebook. Very weird.

Comment: There's some snapping involved that happens at a different rate for the ellipse and for the flat disks. This makes it evident: `Manipulate[Graphics[Rotate[Scale[eye, 12.], -π/4], PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}], {a, 100, 140}]`

Comment: Same on Mac OSX 10.9.5, MMA V10 & V9

Comment: I think you should report it to WRI. I cannot believe that it can be called the expected behavior. Clearly it is a bug.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/unexpected-behavior-of-geometrictransformation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reported the issue to WRI on November 21. On December 16 they confirmed that it is a known bug. (I forgot to update the question till now.)

Answer (score 3):

Just as a complementary and extended comment and as was recently observed in a related [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89931/19960), you get exactly the same problem if, not surprisingly, you use **geometric transformation functions** instead:

Given the initial object to transform:

```
circles = {Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Circle[{0, 0.5}, 0.5]};
```

the OP transformation:

```
t1 = Rotate[Scale[circles, 12], -45 Degree, {0, 0}];
```

is equivalent to:

```
t2 = GeometricTransformation[circles, 
   ScalingTransform[{12, 12}].RotationTransform[-45 Degree, {0, 0}]];
```

and you can check they exactly superimpose:

```
GraphicsGrid@Partition[Table[Graphics[{t1,t2},
    PlotRange -> {{-a, a}, {-a, a}}, ImageSize -> 100], {a, 11, 20}], 5]
```

[image]

You can also observe this strange behaviour just by manually resizing the graphic:

```
Graphics[t2] (* or Graphics[t1] *)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to get around this issue is to make sure that the transformation is calculated explicitly before `Graphics` has to draw it. You can use `TransformedRegion` for this:

```
rotatedCircles = TransformedRegion[
  #, 
  ScalingTransform[{12, 12}, {0, 0}] @* RotationTransform[-45 Degree]
]& /@ circles

Graphics[rotatedCircles]
```

Note that `rotatedCircles` has evaluated and no longer has a transformation wrapper around it any more.