# Exporting a Large Graphic Output Uncrops the Image

Tags: export, image

I want to export an image exactly as it is shown in the notebook, but when I specify a high image resolution, the image saved to disk does not match what is shown in the notebook (the image saved appears to be an uncropped version of the image). 
I am running the following code to produce the graphic:

```
polygonSwirl[
   polygon_: Disk[], thickness_: .8, depth_: 20,   color_: Blue,
   edgeColor_: Black, scalingRate_: .2, xtranslationRate_: .2,
   ytranslationRate_: .2, background_: White, rotationRate_: 1, 
   rotPoint_: {1, 1},  rotModifier_: 5
   ] := Graphics[{EdgeForm[
     Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[thickness], edgeColor}]], color,
    GeometricTransformation[
     polygon,
     Table[
      ScalingTransform[{α/(depth - α)^scalingRate,
                        α/(depth - α)^scalingRate}].TranslationTransform[{-α^
           xtranslationRate, α^ytranslationRate}].RotationTransform[π/(depth - \
α)^rotationRate, rotPoint + rotModifier/α],
      {α, (depth - 1), 1, -1}]
     ],
    }, Background -> background, PlotRangeClipping -> True
   ];

polygonSwirl[
 polygon = Disk[],
 thickness = .4,
 depth = 100,
 color = LightPink,
 edgeColor = Lighter@Purple,
 scalingRate = -.1,
 xtranslationRate = -1,
 ytranslationRate = -1,
 background = LightPink,
 rotationRate = -.999,
 rotPoint = {0, 0},
 rotModifier = 5
 ]
```

The output shown (I took a screenshot) is

[image: screenshot of notebook output]

But the image saved to disk when I run this code is different:

```
 Export["~/Desktop/diskSwirl.png", %, ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

How do I ensure that the image exported matches what is shown in the notebook exactly? Screenshots do not have high enough resolution for my purposes.

Comment: I get the same behaviour (MMA10.2, OSX) . And when I manually resize the graphic in the notebook, the figure changes continuously whether i make it smaller or bigger ! Do you observe the same ? It strongly reminds this  [bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66060/weird-behaviour-when-using-scale-rotate-in-graphics) ...

Comment: Yes, the composition of the shapes changes as well. If you provide more complicated inputs to the function (increase the depth parameter) this becomes more apparent. And more bothersome!

Comment: Hmmm I think this must have to do with Graphics, not Export. It must be redrawing the figure based on canvas size.

Comment: Make the image the `Import` of the `Export`: `img = Import[Export["~/Desktop/diskSwirl.png", polygonSwirl[polygon = Disk[], thickness = .4, depth = 100, color = LightPink, edgeColor = Lighter@Purple, scalingRate = -.1, xtranslationRate = -1, ytranslationRate = -1, background = LightPink, rotationRate = -.999, rotPoint = {0, 0}, rotModifier = 5], ImageResolution -> 500]]`

Comment: I added an answer indicating why I think this is a bug in the notebook display. It could well be related to what @SquareOne mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you have set the option `PlotRangeClipping -> True`, you didn't actually specify a `PlotRange`. This forces `Graphics` to determine the appropriate range automatically. The default for `PlotRange` is `All`, so the result of the `Export` command is actually correct. The notebook display is *not* correct.

But if you want the notebook display to show the cropping, and the exported graphic to have the same appearance, you have to override the default by setting `PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}` (or a similar range).

The fact that the cropping is a bug can be checked by replacing `Disk` with `Rectangle` in your code. Then the output in the notebook is *not* cropped:

[image: swirl2]

So the automatic calculation of `PlotRange` in the case of transformed `Disk`s is done incorrectly, but for `Rectangle`s it works.